# 'Missing 1 required positional argument' and 'unexpected keyword'

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, typeerror

I am creating a GUI, however it will not let me pass the frame through the parameters.
I have returned it and passed it through, however whenever the `Label` function is called it gives me the following error message:

```
"TypeError: Label() missing 1 required positional argument: 'frame'"
```

Code:

```
def Grid(name):
    root=Tk()
    root.resizable (width = False, height = False)
    root.title("Name Generator")
    frame = Frame(root, width=1920, height = 1080,bg="grey")
    frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N+S+E+W)
    button1 = Button(frame, text = "Generate Name", bg="black", fg="white", width = 20, height = 4, font=font2, command=Label)
    button1.pack()
    root.mainloop()
    return frame

def Label(frame):
    name=NameGenerator()
    label1=Label(frame, text = name, bg="red", fg="white", width = 20, height = 4, font=font2)
    label1.pack()



student_name = NameGenerator()
print("student name = " , student_name)
frame=Grid(student_name)
```

On top of this, whenever I change the `Label` variable (under the `Label` function) to a `Label` function rather then a button function, I get the following message:

```
def Label():
    label1=Label(canvas, text="test")
    label1.pack()
    label1.config(text="hello")
```

Error Message:

```
 label1=Label(canvas, text="test")
TypeError: Label() got an unexpected keyword argument 'text'
```

I have looked at other responses however not found them relevant to this. Furthermore, for the positional argument error message I copied exactly the same method/routine for the `student_name` (which worked), however does not with frame.

Answer (score 0):

You use the same name: Label()

```
def Label():  #<----
    label1=Label(canvas, text="test")   #<---
    label1.pack()
    label1.config(text="hello")
```

Comment: Thanks, anything ideas how to fix the other issue?